# How to find non matching count using regex

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have identifiers in a xml file in the structure:

```
<compoundIdentifier>XXX-YYY-ZZZ</compoundIdentifier>
<compoundIdentifier>AAA BB-YYY-ZZZ</compoundIdentifier>
```

Using RegEx in Notepad++  I am trying to identify wrong keys (structure is different then [string] - [string] - [string] )

The string could be any string including white space where `-` escaped as `\-`
so this is also valid:

```
<compoundIdentifier>some key-yet another key-key with \- in it</compoundIdentifier>
```

How can I find identifiers that doesn't match this pattern?

For example:

```
<compoundIdentifier>YYY-ZZZ</compoundIdentifier>
<compoundIdentifier>XXX</compoundIdentifier>
<compoundIdentifier>XXX--</compoundIdentifier>
```

Comment: You need to provide a little more structure. First, the second id in your first snippet is invalid according to your criteria - is that intentional? Are all identifiers just uppercase letters? Are there always three letter groups?

Comment: Thanks boris- i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xml is as simple as that, you could use something like this:

```
^<compoundIdentifier>(?!(?:(?:[^-\\]|\\.)+-){2}(?:[^-\\]|\\.)+</compoundIdentifier>$).+</compoundIdentifier>$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hW1lQ7)

`^` matches the beginning of the line.

`(?!(?:(?:[^-\\]|\\.)+-){2}(?:[^-\\]|\\.)+)` is a negative lookahead to prevent the match of the particular structure you don't want to match.

`[^-]+` matches one or more non `-` characters.

`(?:(?:[^-\\]|\\.)+-){2}` matches two groups of non-dash characters followed by a dash.

`.+</compoundIdentifier>$` matches any string that is left till the closing tag on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
>((?!([^-]+-){2}[^-]+).+)<
```

This will also capture the `<>` but the first capturing group will have it's contents.
Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/lM6kP2)